# Multiple Provision Profiles in Build -> Archive for TestFlight

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, beta-testing, testflight

I am making my .ipa for an app I'm about to upload to TestFlight, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it available to all of my teammates.

When I make a provisioning profile at developer.apple.com, I can only register one device per profile. (Right?)

When I create the .ipa in Build -> Archive, I can only use one Provisioning Profile. (Right??)

So this means I can only make an .ipa work for one device. (Right???)

This can't be right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ad-hoc distribution profile can support more than one device. Check you are making one of those, rather than a development profile. It's a different tab in the portal. The device UDIDs can all be added in the portal as well.

Alternatively, if you're on the enterprise program, you don't need to gather UDIDs and can install on devices without them. There is some confusion over whether this is technically against Apple's terms but in practice it is being used by many developers for beta testing.